# How to Retrieve the Two Youngest Users From a Database, up to Two Given Limit Dates

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Let's assume the following persistence object...

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class UserPo {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private LocalTime birthDate;
}
```

... and the following repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserPo, Long> {

  Optional<UserPo> findDistinctTopByOrderByBirthDateDesc(final LocalDate limitDate);
}
```

`findDistinctTopByOrderByBirthDateDesc` returns the youngest user up to the specified date.

Now let's assume the following 8 users:

```
---------------------------------------
ID | NAME     | BIRTH_DATE (YYYY-MM-DD)
---------------------------------------
 1 | Joe      | 1980-10-25
 2 | John     | 1951-11-30 <===
 3 | Matthew  | 1988-09-27
 4 | Paul     | 1946-02-28
 5 | Erik     | 1987-07-11
 6 | Michael  | 1996-03-03
 7 | David    | 1990-08-15
 8 | Steven   | 2000-11-01 <===
```

I need a query that given 2 dates, returns the youngest users up to these 2 dates. So for instance, the query input is `limitDate1` and `limitDate2`, and assuming `limitDate1` is `2023-01-01` and `LimitDate2` is `1952-01-01`, the query shall return user 8 and user 2.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it’s not possible. Why not just execute this query two times with two different parameters?
Btw, maybe window functions may help, but I can barely say that this approach will be more efficient.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, name, birthDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY birthDate DESC) AS rn
  FROM UserPo
)
SELECT 
  (SELECT name FROM cte WHERE birthDate <= :limitDate1 AND rn = 1) AS youngest1,
  (SELECT name FROM cte WHERE birthDate <= :limitDate2 AND rn = 1) AS youngest2
FROM DUAL;
```

The signature of the method will be something like this:

```
Object[] findYoungestUsers(@Param("limitDate1") LocalDate limitDate1, @Param("limitDate2") LocalDate limitDate2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I need to stick with jpql  as we have different databases depending on the environment (i.e. Oracle in production, PostgreSQL in dev, etc.).